# umbraco uWebshop payment mathod of quickpay

Tags: umbraco7

we need quickpay payment option in uwebshop E-commerce

is any one have example of quickpay payment option in uwebshop

Thanks
Mk

Answer (score 1):

You find them on their [github](https://github.com/uWebshop/PaymentProviders) and [here](http://docs.uwebshop.com/providers/guides/creating-a-payment-provider/) are some docs.